# When does Rowf's Badge Shop get new inventory?

Tags: paper-mario

How often (or under what conditions) does Rowf's Badge Shop in Toad Town get new or different badges?  I'd hate to miss a great badge because I didn't visit the shop at the right time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The badges won't change before you buy them. After that, the empty slots will be filled up when you re-enter town (if new badges are available, usually after a chapter finishes). So, don't worry, just buy the ones you don't actually need later when you got some spare coins.

Comment: Also, [here's](http://www.mariowiki.com/Badges#Paper_Mario_2) a list of all badges, including a mention after which chapter which badges can be bought

Answer (score 2):

If you are close to the end of the game all of the badges should be available. To make him change his inventory all you have to do is go in and out of the door to the flower fields and they will be different every time. The badges are pretty expensive so this also Gives you a good chance to get some coins too. Just equip the money money, pay off, and zap tap badges. And as long as you have at least 50 hp just head up to the north west path(upper left path). Cross the thorns and start a battle with the bee there. Keep selecting do nothing until your hp is low and then kill the bees if the zap tap (electric touch effect) has not killed them already by itself. You will get 20 coins every battle. Go back to toad town to check badges and replenish health and repeat until you have all the badges that you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to the ArQAde and thanks for your additional info - I never observed this effect but then again I usually didn't wait long to buy all new badges... However, please do _not_ abuse the `edit` feature to make a comment, you'll be able to do so in time when e.g. this answer got some upvotes (like the one from me :)